# Prove that $x^3-x = y^2+1$ has no integer solution

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, diophantine-equations, integers

Prove that $x^3-x = y^2+1$ has no integer solution:

I began the proof by case distinction considering the cases if x,y are both even, if x,y both odd, if x even, y odd and the last one if x odd and y even.

If x,y are even: then $x^3$ and $x$ are always even, so is $x^3-x$ even too. $y^2$ is even and the term $y^2+1$ is always odd. Hence the equality in this case is false.

If x,y are odd: then $x^3$ and $x$ are odd, so is $x^3-x$ always even. $y^2$ is odd, but $y^2+1$ is always even. This means that the equality could possibly be true.

(The other two cases are then analogously proven)

How should I continue?

Answer (score 6):

HINT :

Instead of mod 2, considering in mod 3 helps.

> The LHS is divisible by 3, but the RHS isn't.

Comment: Clarification: The LHS $x^3 - x$ can be written as $x(x^2-1)$ or $x(x+1)(x-1)$, so this is a product of three consecutive integers. One of those integers (and so also the LHS) is a multiple of 3 if we check case by case for 0,1, and 2.

Comment: The RHS $y^2+1$ has modulo $y^2$ + 1, so checking case by case for 0,1 and 2 again all perfect squares are 0, 1 (mod 3), so $y^2+1$ can be either 1,2 mod (3), so it is not divisible by 3.